# how to apply localization and Internationalization approach using spring framework with elasticsearch backend?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, internationalization, spring-internationalization

I am using Spring framework with elasticsearch as the backend to store results such as item description, price, expert notes, etc. It is working perfectly for the English domain. I need to add additional language support for this. I have added the properties file for button labels and all the HTML markup except for the data in elasticsearch. I have the corresponding translation for the elasticsearch data. My question is how can I use this translated data? So far I have come up with the following options:

1. Create separate elasticsearch index for the translated data and query the required field from this index for showing the translated text.
2. Store the translated data in database and query that data at runtime for translation.
3. Store the translated data in properties file and read these properties for translation.

Has anyone done this before? Are there any other options I didn't mention? What approach did you take?

Comment: I imagine that you have a index of products. Is product registration done in English and are you responsible for translating or can registration be done in several languages?

Comment: Registration will be done in English only @rabbitbr

Comment: So I imagine that you will translate specific fields like name, description, etc. In this case I would create fields for each of these mentioned fields and using the analyzer for each language. We use this strategy and it works well.
Would be like this:
{
   "mappings": {
     "properties": {
       "description": {
         "type": "text",
         "fields": {
           "pt-br": {
             "type": "text",
             "analyzer": "english"
           },
           "fr": {
             "type": "text",
             "analyzer": "france"
           }
         }...

Comment: This is so clever! So basically, in the same index... have different keys for description e.g description-fr (French description), description-es (Spanish description) etc. with the corresponding analyzer @rabbitbr or I understood is totally wrong?

Comment: exactly. when the search occurs, you pass the search term and the language so you mount the query to search in the language field. Ex: A Brazilian, in Brazil, searches his system.
{
   "query": {
     "match": {
       "description.pt-br": "my_term"
     }
   }
}

Comment: Thank you so much @rabbitbr. You solved it so well!